# Search and save a line containing a set of chars from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm using `readlines()` to read the data into my two arrays, and I need to get a specific line.

problem:

I'm not sure what string or array method to use to get the specific line containing `'...blah'` (my class' line/name of the group.)

I prefer to not save the entire file content into these two variables if possible. I'd rather just "search" through the file and save the two  specific lines I need into `student_info` and `class_usernames`.

```
student_info =  File.readlines ('/etc/passwd')
class_usernames = File.readlines ('/etc/group')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) on that array:

```
student_info    = File.readlines('/etc/passwd').detect { |s| s.include?('...blah') }
class_usernames = File.readlines('/etc/group').detect { |s| s =~ /\.\.\.blah/ }
```

And btw please do not use a whitespace between the method name and the parameter list.

Comment: did not work for the student_info i supplied the name of the class and find anything by that name.

Comment: i also dont see detect as a method of the string or array class

Comment: @Marcusw1 : `detect` is defined in the `Enumerable` Module. Collection type classes like `Array`or `Hash` include this mixin, therefore `detect` is available on an array. You might want to follow the link above.

Answer (score 0):

```
student_info = File.readlines('/etc/passwd').grep(/blah/).first
```

`grep` is also a method from Enumerable. It returns an array of matches, of which the first is taken (by `.first`).